# How to derive the rank nullity theorem through the first isomorphism theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I remember that in my first linear algebra class, in section the GSI mentioned that the rank-nullity theorem was a consequence of the first isomorphism theorem. Now in my second linear algebra couse, the instructor used it to prove the RNT, but used the result:
$$
\dim(V/U) = \dim V − \dim U
$$

Earlier in the course, this theorem was proved using the RNT and the quotient map. Is there another way to prove the rank-nullity theorem from the first isomorphism theorem or does the validity of the statement rely on the fact there are other ways to prove the dimension of a quotient space?

Comment: You can prove the dimension result easily: take a basis for $U$, and extend to a basis for $V$ then project to the quotient. The non-zero elements form a basis (spanning is clear since the projection map is surjective, proving independence is an exercise in understanding quotient spaces).

Comment: The equality $\dim V=\dim U + \dim(V/U)$ can be proved without RNT: Take a subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $V=U\oplus W$; then $\dim V=\dim U+\dim W$, and $\dim W = \dim(V/U)$ because $W \cong V/U$.